# gpsd fails to start on boot, but does manually

Tags: centos, systemd, gpsd

Ok, I know there are variations of this problem out there. I have looked at nearly every one that looks like it might be pertinent and nothing works.

I have a USB serial device that I set up to be on /dev/ttyGPS that provides gps information. I have gpsd installed and enabled. Also true for gpsd.socket. I can manually start these services (or stop then start them) without issue. But for some reason on boot they do not start. The journal output for gpsd is:

`systemd[1]: Dependency failed for GPS (Global Positioning System) Daemon.
 systemd[1]: Job gpsd.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.`

Which is cryptic enough. I looked at gpsd.socket and see this:

`systemd[1]: gpsd.socket failed to listen on sockets: Address already in use
systemd[1]: Failed to listen on GPS (Global Positioning System) Daemon Sockets.
systemd[1]: Unit gpsd.socket entered failed state.`

I have tried setting the load USB option to "true" and "false". I have tried to look at what is on port 2947, but nothing is there. I have even tried to get a work around by just automatically restarting the service every 5 seconds, but that doesn't seem to work for a failed state.

Anybody have any idea what I might be able to do to figure out why the port is blocked on boot? Or barring that I would be just as happy to delay the start until after boot-up is finished and would act like a manual boot. This is on CentOS 7 system.
Many thanks

Edit: Here are the service files
gpsd:

```
[Unit]
Description=GPS (Global Positioning System) Daemon
Requires=gpsd.socket
# Needed with chrony SOCK refclock
After=chronyd.service

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/gpsd
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/gpsd -N $OPTIONS

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Also=gpsd.socket
```

gpsd.socket:

```
[Unit]
Description=GPS (Global Positioning System) Daemon Sockets

[Socket]
ListenStream=/var/run/gpsd.sock
ListenStream=127.0.0.1:2947
SocketMode=0600

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

And the /etc/sysconfig/gpsd file contents for OPTIONS

```
# Options for gpsd, including serial devices
OPTIONS="/dev/ttyGPS"
# Set to 'true' to add USB devices automatically via udev
USBAUTO="true"
```

Comment: Have you customized the systemd unit files? Seeing those might help.

Comment: I have not customized them. I. Did try to changed the service to add a restart option on gpsd. But when that didn't help, I reverted back. I can still post them if that would be helpful. Still want them?

Comment: So where I'm at now is I have added a udev rule to the gps device that when it is detected it kickes off a script that goes and restarts the gpsd.socket and then gpsd services. Tested two boots and it seems to get it going. No idea if that is the right approach, but it is working for me.